# How to hide the constants I defined in static library?

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I have a library of my own. And there are lots of constants defined in headers (for example animation duration). But, all my headers are visible and changeable. How can I prevent others to change my default values?

There are some const value in headers of Apple libraries like this:

CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCATransitionMoveIn
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);

Comment: If people are determined to change your code, and the behavior of it, they will find a way.  Not much to do about that.  However, to limit accidental changes and side effects, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is still, well, C.  Maybe older systems had issues, which is why you see the macros there.  Anyway, you should still be safe with any built-in type.

If you declare something as "extern" the compiler will treat it something like, "OK, I see that someone has declared and external thingy.  I don't have to know what it is, because some external unit will define it.  The linker will handle the rest.

That paragraph will get me in trouble with the C-police, but it's close enough for a practical explanation.  Thus, you can do this in your header file...

```
extern int const TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything;
```

And then, in one of your implementation files (outside of the @implementation/@end section)...

```
int const TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything = 42;
```

Note, in "modern" Xcode versions, you can do the same thing with objects.  Note the "const" which means we have a constant-pointer-to-NSString.

```
// In header
extern NSString * const TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverythingString;

// In source
NSString * const TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverythingString = @"42";
```